# Fourier transform of a measure

Tags: measure-theory, topological-groups

I'm a bit confused - How is the Fourier transform of a **measure** on a compact abelian group defined? specifically the Fourier transform of a measure on $\mathbb{T}$ the unit circle in the complex plain.

Comment: This is developed quite thoroughly at http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/the-fourier-transform/, for example.  Google is helpful with such an inquiry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\mu$ is a measure on the compact abelian group $G$ and $\gamma$ is in the dual group, 
$$\hat{\mu}(\gamma) = \int_G (-g, \gamma)\ d\mu(g)$$
In the case ${\mathbb T}$, the dual group is $\mathbb Z$, acting on $\mathbb T$ by $(n, \omega) = \omega^n$.